# Python time data does not match format %B %d, %Y

Tags: python, datetime

When i use **datetime.datetime.strptime('Apr 29, 2020', '%B %d, %Y')** i see the following:

ValueError: time data 'Apr 29, 2020' does not match format '%B %d, %Y'

What is wrong with the format ?

Comment: That is because you need to write `April` and not `Apr` , or change to `%b` if you don't want to write the full name of the month. (`%B` = full name)

Comment: When it worked for May and not for Apr. I didn't even suspect the format. Thanks for pointing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

`%B` works for full month name like `April`:

```
In [3]: datetime.datetime.strptime('April 29, 2020', '%B %d, %Y')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 29, 0, 0)
```

While `%b` works for you in this case `Apr`:

```
In [4]: datetime.datetime.strptime('Apr 29, 2020', '%b %d, %Y')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 29, 0, 0)
```

Take a look at [This Link](https://strftime.org/) to get better clue.